# Why does java.awt.Color return RGB values?

Tags: java, awt

I've been searching around and haven't been able to find anything. One reason is that i don't know what to start searching. :/

So basically i was playing around with colors and then i used `System.out.println(java.awt.Color.black)` and the output was `java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=0]` which kinda surprised me as i thought the output would be something like `java.awt.Color@2a33fae0` because from what i could find the 'black' variable in java.awt.Color is type java.awt.Color, why and how is this the output?

Comment: Have you looked at the `toString` of `java.awt.Color`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you get when printing an object reference is the String returned by the toString method. The class Color defines a toString method that produces the output you see there.

Answer (score 1):

In java the print statement uses the `toString` implementation for the class. So if you don't implement it, it will use the `toString` from `Object` and that's why you get the output like `java.awt.Color@2a33fae0` but for `Color` it is using the `toString` from `Color` so you get the `RGB` value. They just chose to implement the `toString` this way they could have chosen hex or any other representation.